# How to remove transform attribute of svg document?

Tags: c#, xml, svg

I have created an `svg document` with only 1 `flowRoot` element in it and then saved it. Then when i

reopened that document in visual studio i saw a `transform` attribute in the `flowRoot` element. But i

created some s
svg document earlier also , at that time i didn`t saw any such attribute there. What does this

attribute means and how i can get rid of it.? I am using inkscape for creating svg document.

Comment: FYI: flowRoot isn't supported by any of the web browsers.

Comment: I never said that i opened it in any browser :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [SVG transform attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#TransformAttribute) specifies a translation or scale or rotation or skew or some combination thereof to apply to the contents of the SVG element.

For example, this moves whatever you are drawing 350 units to the right and 250 units down (assuming you haven't got any other transforms):

```
transform="translate(350,250)"
```

Transforms are most useful when you have several elements grouped together and you want to move them (or rotate them or whatever) as a single group.

Inkscape writes SVG.  Transforms are part of SVG.  What's the problem?